# EC2 - Setting Environment Variables

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, environment-variables

I need to set some environment variables on my EC2 instance. Every where I look says to use the standard command:

```
export MY_VARIABLE=MY_VALUE
```

When I connect via SSH though I get this message in the intro text:

> Changes made via SSH  WILL BE LOST if the instance is replaced by
>   auto-scaling

This makes me think I should be setting the variables in a script every time an instance is replaced but I can't find any documentation to explain how to do this.

Is there a way I can set these variables at instance creation time?

Comment: Is this an Elastic Beanstalk managed instance?

Comment: It is, I should of mentioned that. Found a solution in the end below. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should of mentioned I was using Elastic Beanstalk, so you can't stop your EC2 instance to add them to the User Data.

I found that adding a .config file to the .ebextensions folder and adding the values like:

```
option_settings:
  - option_name: PRODUCTION
    value: 1
  - option_name: AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
    value: mysecretkey
  - option_name: AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
    value: myaccesskey
```

and then deploying the app works.